# how to inject service to view Model in mvvm light

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I try to use dependency injection to inject service into view model. try this code

ViewModelLocator

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public static MainViewModel _main;

        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);


            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IAccountService, AccountService>();

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public IMainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMainViewModel>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public LoginViewModel Login
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cleans up all the resources.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Cleanup()
        {

        }
    }
```

MainViewModel

```
public interface IMainViewModel
    {

    }
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel(IAccountService accountService)
        {
            _accountService = accountService;
        }
    }
```

my LoginViewModel

```
public interface ILoginViewModel
{
    ICommand Authorize { get; set; }
}
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMainViewModel
{

    private IAccountService _accountService;

    public LoginViewModel(IAccountService _accountService)
    {
        this._accountService = _accountService;
        Authorize = new RelayCommand(() => CheckAuthorized(), () => true);
    }

    public ICommand Authorize { get; private set; } 

}
```

and this my LoginView

```
public partial class Login : UserControl
{
    ILoginViewModel _loginViewModel;
    public Login(ILoginViewModel _loginViewModel)
    {
        this._loginViewModel = _loginViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _loginViewModel;
    }
}
```

my question is, when i try to inject in my View, the object reference is null,
how can i use DI in mvvm light?

Comment: I'm confused; the title of your question implies that you're trying to inject ``AccountService`` into ``LoginViewModel``, but your comment at the end implies that you're trying to put it into ``LoginView``. Which is it?

Comment: oh sorry my fault, i mean LoginViewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to inject ILoginViewModel into the Login view but seems like ILoginViewModel is not registered so you may need to register the same

```
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);


        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IAccountService, AccountService>();

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>(); //register view models
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ILoginViewModel, LoginViewModel>();
    }
```

thanks @Jason for pointing this out

perhaps by mistake LoginViewModel is implementing IMainViewModel instead of ILoginViewModel

so need to be corrected this way

```
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase, ILoginViewModel
{
    ...
}
```

also implemtent IMainViewModel in MainViewModel to make it resolve via the container

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMainViewModel 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: There's also the problem that ``LoginViewModel`` doesn't implement ``ILoginViewModel``. I'm too tired to come up with the right inheritance structure for this, but I do know that the VMs should be implementing their interfaces - and unless I'm mistaken, ``LoginViewModel`` should inherit from ``MainViewModel`` and not implement ``IMainViewModel``. But I could be wrong about that last one