# simple sample to use depedency injection to inject service in view model mvvm light

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

i try to use DI in mvvm light like [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073471/how-to-inject-service-to-view-model-in-mvvm-light)

can some one give me simple sample to use

> depedency injection to inject service in view model mvvm?

can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is based on IoC container you using. If you are using PRISM, you need to register the service contract and concrete type in bootstrapper.

```
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        this.container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>();
    }
```

The registered contracts will be injected through constructor in your viewmodel.

```
    public MyViewModel(IMyService myService)
    {
    }
```

The life time of dependencies can also be controlled using LifeTime Managers. More information on that,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx